# List of all programming languages in Select Field

Tags: python

I am trying to create a **WtForms SelectField** which will show all the various programming languages available to choose from.

Its almost impossible to type all the programming languages [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) in the select field. How to implement this kind of select field.

**Code**

```
class SkillForm(Form):
    skill = SelectField('Languages', choices=[('c++', 'C++'), ('python', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate_skill(self, field):
        if Skill.query.filter_by(author_id=current_user.id).filter(Skill.skill==field.data.lower()).first():
            raise ValidationError('Skill already exists.')
```

I have just added three skills for just testing purpose and it works and i need to include all the languages possible and its almost impossible to write them all in choices, so what other option do i get from that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: down voters please care to comment.

Comment: Show your code - so maybe people will not downvote.

Comment: Create script to get all programming languages from Wikipedia and create select field or whatever you want.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question - but you should restrict your drop down to the languages that you need to hire for, rather than every language under the sun. Do you really want to hire someone for `ABC` programming? How about `FoxPro` which was discontinued in 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the languages from the website running a script:

```
#Get the html
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages')
html = response.read()

#Parse it with beautifulsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

langs = []

#Parse all the links.
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #Last link after ZPL, the last language.
    if link.get_text() == u'Top':
        break
    if link.get_text() == u'edit':
        pass
    else:
        langs.append(link.get_text())

# find u'See also'
see_also_index_ = langs.index(u'See also')
# strip out headers
langs = langs[see_also_index_+1:]

print langs
```

Comment: @kjtl: Oh.. Darn. Well... Haha. Just add an if statement, don't append to langs if the link is an edit.

Comment: @kjtl: Updated, removes edits... The only question, is there something else I'm missing lol.

Comment: :-) the start node for the list .
I did the following 
# remove u'edit'
langs = [x for x in langs if x != u'edit' ]
# find u'See also'
see_also_index_ = langs.index(u'See also')
# strip out headers
langs = langs[see_also_index_+1:]

Comment: @kjtl: Please, feel free to!

Answer (score 0):

It is for the same reason, I have created a small Github repository with a list of programming languages listed on the [Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages). It contains HTML checkboxes and dropdowns. Hope this helps someone in the future

You can check out the repo here.
https://github.com/chilarai/list-of-programming-languages